# Local References in ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency

In `ConcurrentHashMap`, segments is marked final (and thus will never change), but the method `ensureSegment` creates a method-local copy, ss, of segments upon which to operate.

Does anybody know this purpose? which benefit we can get?

**Update**:

I search from google, get one page which explained ConcurrentHashMap in JDK7 [The Concurrency Of ConcurrentHashMap](http://www.burnison.ca/articles/the-concurrency-of-concurrenthashmap), below are excerpts

```
Local References
```

> Even though segments is marked final (and thus will never change), Doug Lea prudently creates a method-local copy, ss, of segments upon which to operate. **Such defensive programming allows a programmer to not worry about otherwise-volatile instance member references changing during execution of a method (i.e. inconsistent reads).** Of course, this is simply a new reference and does not prevent your method from seeing changes to the referent.

Can anyone explain the bold text?

Comment: It might help to link to the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no semantic difference between accessing a `final` field and accessing a local variable holding a copy of the `final` field’s value. However, it is an established pattern to copy fields into local variables in performance critical code.

Even in cases where it does not make a difference (that depends on the state of the HotSpot optimizer), it will save at least some bytes in the method’s code.

Each access to an instance field, be it `final` or not (the only exception being compile-time constants), will get compiled as two instructions, first pushing the `this` reference onto the operand stack via [`aload_0`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.aload_n), then performing a [`getfield`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.getfield) operation, which has a two byte index to the constant pool entry describing the field. In other words, each field access needs four bytes in the method’s code, whereas reading a local variable needs only one byte if the variable is one of the method’s first four (counting `this` as a local variable), which is the case here (see [`aload_n`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.aload_n)).

So storing a field’s value in a local variable when it is going to be accessed multiple times is a good behavior to protect against changes of a mutable variable and to avoid the cost of a `volatile` read and still doesn’t hurt even when it is obsolete as in the case of a `final` field as it will even produce more compact byte code. And in a simple interpreted execution, i.e. before the optimizer kicks in, the single local variable access might indeed be faster than the detour via the `this` instance.

Answer (score 1):

The array is marked `final`, but the array elements are not (can not). So each array element can be set or replaced, for example using:

```
this.segments[i] = ...
```

`ensureSegment` in Java 7 uses a different method to set the array element, using `sun.misc.Unsafe`, for improved performance when concurrently calling the method. This is not what a "regular" developer should do.

A local variable

```
final Segment<K,V>[] ss = this.segments;
```

is typically used to ensure (well - to increase that probability) that `ss` is in a CPU register, and not re-read from memory, for the duration of this method. I guess that would not be needed in this case, as the compiler can infer that. Using `ss` does make the following lines slightly shorter, maybe that's why it is used.